# Chrome extension - listening to YouTube events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, google-chrome-extension

```
var ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onPlayerChange');

function onPlayerChange(newState) {
  alert('do something at least...');
  if(newState == 0) {
    alert('movie has stopped');
  }
}
```

This is how I try to listen to YouTube events with a Google Chrome extension. It doesn't give me any error at all, even though it should when the movie has finished. Or at least when the state has changed. Does anyone know what is wrong?
Console doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Are you doing this **after** the swf object is inside the DOM?

Comment: How can you wait for the **swf** to be loaded? Isn't "DOMContentLoaded" enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine on Firefox because the player is Flash. However Chrome supports HTML5 and the player is HTML5 Video Player. So there is no element which has "movie_player" id. Are you sure your video player is Flash on Chrome. Right click the video and see player info in context menu. [More details about YouTube HTML5 Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Youtube HTML5 player is currently in trial, so you should detect user's player mode and add a fallback for it at least YT completely use HTML5.

Comment: Your right, it works if i write it with "javascript: ..." but as a firefox extension I can't make it work (contrary to the OP, I'm developing a firefox extension, but should be almost the same). It requires a third (boolean) parameter, and the second parameter of addEvenListener to be a callback, which is done, but the event never fires, and no other error is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 `video` element fires its own events. Right now, it looks like the easiest way to get at it is by class name (since it doesn’t have an id):

```
var videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];
```

Video elements fire a bunch of events, which you can find listed [here in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#mediaevents).

For example:

```
videoElement.addEventListener('pause', function(){ alert('paused!'); })
```